# restart counter in netstat

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

I am using Ubuntu.

I need to count the number of packet received in a specific interface. I found this can be done using netstat. However, I need to count starting from t=zero until a specific time I want (t=...) and the counter shall be start from zero

This can be done if everytime I restart the computer so the counter starts from zero, but I just want to know if there is any other solution to capture how many packets on a specific interface within a certain time I want.

Comment: Interface stats are available via SNMP.

Comment: @zoredache : yes, and also in other tools that basically take the stat from /proc/sys.. but i am curious how to make the packet counter to 0, without having to restart the machine all the time

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/23687/how-do-i-clear-the-interface-stats-on-linux

Comment: @Zoredache : lol linkception :D thank you (unfortunately you post in comment, not the answer. I can not accept the answer)

Comment: If that question does have the answers you need, then I'll vote to close this question as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to reset counters without restarting ( or unload-load cycle nic card module if nic is loaded via dynamic module.)

[Virtual zero-ing](http://fixunix.com/sun/114674-netstat-counters.html) concept is discussed here though.

Answer (score 0):

use nstat(coming from iproute2 instead of deprecated net-tools) instead, ref https://superuser.com/questions/1590901/reset-netstat-statistics